# How to create a class that will return an array or single item?

Tags: php, class

I am writing a class that I would like to be able to call later and have it return an array of values but it is returning only one.

I would like to be able to use my class like this. If I specify one user id new Blog([10]) then it shouldn't return an array but only one instance. If I specify more than one user id then it should return an array of items.

I am trying to create something similar to how Laravel works where you can say $posts = Posts::all(); or $posts = Post::where('id', 10)->first(); and in the first one it would return an array of all posts and in second it would return only one.

**Example usage:**

```
// Get one user's blog
$blog = new Blog([10]); // specify user ids

echo $blog->user->name;      // Jane Smith
echo $blog->posts->title;    // How to draw
echo $blog->posts->body;     // In this post, I will teach you...
echo $blog->posts->created;  // 2018-12-01
echo $blog->theme;           // light/dark/other
echo $blog->is_awesome;      // no

// Get blogs for users - 10, 20, 30
$blogs = new Blog([10, 20, 30]); // specify user ids

foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
    echo $blog->user->name;     // John Doe
    echo $blog->posts->title;   // 10 ways to live
    echo $blog->posts->body;    // Hello, in this post I will..
    echo $blog->posts->created; // 2018-12-31
    echo $blog->theme;          // light/dark/other
    echo $blog->is_awesome;     // yes
}
```

**My class**

```
Class Blog
{
    public $users;
    public $posts;
    public $comments;
    public $theme;
    public $is_awesome;

    function __construct($users)
    {
        $this->users     = new stdClass();
        $this->users->id = $users; // array of ids

        foreach ($this->users as $user) {
            $this->user->name = self::getUsername($user->id)  // John
            $this->posts      = self::getPosts($user->id);    // array of posts
            $this->comments   = self::getComments($user->id); // array of comments
            $this->theme      = self::getTheme($user->id);    // light/dark/other

            if ($this->theme == 'dark') {
                $this->is_awesome = 'yes';
            } else {
                $this->is_awesome = 'no';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A **constructor** is designed to return a new instance of **its** class.

Comment: Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Create static functions. For an example the Blog::all([user_id1, ... ])  returns array of blogs, Blog::one(user_id) returns array of user's blogs

Comment: @AlexanderChernin wouldn't I have to repeat the same code in both function with the only difference being one or multiple results?

Comment: Ok. Create the static function Blog::blogs([id1, id2,... ]) returns array of items

Comment: this feels bad ... personally, I'd advise to have a Blog class that loads a blog via one method and loads blogs via another. E.g. `getBlogById(?int $id)` and `getBlogsByIds(?array $ids)` - this allows much more dynamic and readable classes

Answer (score 0):

I understand why you're trying to do, and since you asked another way, here it is. One of the approaches is to write a [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) to retrieve yours blogs:

```
class Blog {
  public static function fetchBlogsByIds() {
    // [...]
  }
  // [...]
}
```

Then you call the method this way:

```
$blogs = Blog::fetchBlogsByIds(ids) {
  $blogs = array();
  foreach($ids as $id) {
    $blogs[] = new Blog($id); // appending a new Blog entry
  }
  return $blogs;
}
```

You could also write a **collection** class named, for example **`BlogCollection`** and provide to it a constructor relying on an array of ids.

```
class BlogCollection {

  // Builds the collection by the ids
  function __construct(ids) {
    // [...] similar implementation as fetchBlogsByIds() above
  }

  // [...]
}
```

Then you can retrieve your blogs this way:

```
blogs = new BlogCollection([10, 11]);
```

If you want to use `foreach` with your custom collection, you can make it implementing [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) or [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).

Comment: *static methods are deprecated in PHP 7* - erm please check this as I think you misunderstand the comment in the manual.

Comment: this is what I already had.. how would I solve the one or many problem? should I do a loop and add to an array?

Comment: @Liga, I added more details in the block code. Is it clearer?